# How to pass user input inside an eventReactive expression Shiny/R

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf

I am having trouble with creating a new variable in dplyr::mutate using a user inputted variable through selectInput in the UI.

```
gwrdata <- eventReactive(input$rungwr, {
  sp_shape <- as(data(), "Spatial")
  bwG <- gwr.sel(formula(), data = sp_shape, gweight = gwr.Gauss, verbose = FALSE)
  gwrG <- gwr(formula(), data = sp_shape, bandwidth = bwG, 
              gweight = gwr.Gauss, hatmatrix = TRUE)
  sf_gwr <- st_as_sf(gwrG$SDF)
  bins <- 3
  browser()
  sf_gwr <- mutate(sf_gwr, parBin = cut2(sf_gwr[, input$inVar], 
                   g = bins, levels.mean = TRUE))
  sf_gwr <- mutate(sf_gwr, sigBin = cut2(localR2, g = bins, levels.mean = TRUE))
  bvColors = c("#e8e8e8", "#dfb0d6", "#be64ac", "#ace4e4",
             "#a5add3", "#8c62aa", "#5ac8c8", "#5698b9", "#3b4994")
  levels(sf_gwr$parBin) <- 1:bins
  levels(sf_gwr$sigBin) <- 1:bins
  sf_gwr <- mutate(sf_gwr, value = paste(parBin, '-', sigBin, sep = ''))
  sf_gwr
})
```

There are two mutate functions. The process works fine if it is hard coded like it is with `localR2`.  However when using the `sf_gwr[,input$inVar]` the following error is given.

Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'st_geometry<-' applied to an object of class "list".

Does this have something to do with the subsetting in the mutate function?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are carrying over the geometry column with single square bracket. try indexing with double square bracket...i.e. sf_gwr[[,input$inVar]]. Or try setting geometry to NULL e.g. sf_gwr[,input$inVar] %>% st_set_geometry(NULL)